# is there the way to get environment variable in HP-UX by pid

Tags: server, process, pid, hp-ux, environ

I want to know the method the way to get environment variable in HPUX from pid 
by ps command, file, or programming.

it is possible to get variable

```
# /proc/$pid/environ in environ  or ps e -ww -p $pid in linux
# ps ewww pid in aix
# pargs in solaris
```

HP-UX : use gdb to track but there is no gdb on a server(HPUX) and it's impossible to install it.

let me know that.

Comment: did you try `ps -fp PID`

Comment: no output to check environment variable in usnig "ps -fp PID"

Answer (score 1):

If you can install software onto this host, the latest  [HP-UX Linker, Libraries and Tools](https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/free-software/HPUX-Linker) patch should give you the `pargs(1)` command:

```
[ hp-ux_ia64 sw ] $ /usr/ccs/bin/pargs -v
HP pstack/pldd/pargs version B.12.67 for HP Itanium(R) Systems.
[ hp-ux_ia64 sw ] $ /usr/ccs/bin/pargs -h

        usage:  pargs [-h] [-v] {-a pid | -e pid}

        Given the pid of a running process, pargs prints process arguments and all
        environment variables and its values.
        pargs works by attaching to the process to read its memory.
[ hp-ux_ia64 sw ] $ ps -fu ranga
     UID   PID  PPID  C    STIME TTY       TIME COMMAND
 ranga  9949  9923  0  Mar 17  pts/3     0:00 /usr/bin/sh /home/ranga/bin/tmux
 ranga 16795 10007  0 10:40:06 pts/7     0:00 ssh hp-ux_ia64
 ranga  9952  9949  0  Mar 17  pts/3     0:00 tmux
 ranga 16538 16376  1 21:35:16 pts/4     0:00 ps -fu ranga
 ranga  9918  9916  0  Mar 17  ?         0:04 sshd: ranga@pts/3
 ranga  9954     1  2  Mar 17  ?         1:15 tmux
[ hp-ux_ia64 sw ] $ PHSS_44731/C-MIN/usr/ccs/bin/pargs -e 9949
SOCKS_CONF=/home/ranga/etc/socks.conf
MAIL=/var/mail/ranga
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/contrib/bin:/opt/langtools/bin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/home/ranga
EDITOR=vim
TZ=IST-5:30
ERASE=^H
PS1=[ \h \W ] \$
SHLVL=1
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
SFTP_PERMIT_CHMOD=1
HOME=/home/ranga
TERMINFO=/home/ranga/lib/terminfo
LOGNAME=ranga
SSH_CONNECTION=1.4.5.1 44584 1.2.2.2 22
SSH_CLIENT=1.1.0.6 44584 22
SHLIB_PATH=/home/ranga/local/lib
SFTP_UMASK=
_=/home/ranga/bin/tmux
USER=ranga
TERM=rxvt-256color
SOCKS5_SERVER=socks-server.ranga.com
LINES=70
```

Even if you can't install the patch, the `pargs` executable can be extracted from it and used.

If you can copy files out of this host, you could

- use [gcore(1)](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/gcore-for-hpux/td-p/3361569#.Xm8oVpzhUiY) to generate a core file of the process
- copy this core file along with the executable and the appropriate version of
  libc (32-bit or 64-bit, use pldd(1) to confirm) to an environment
  where gdb is available
- use gdb to hack into the __envp string table

  ```
  [ hp-ux-ia64 ~ ] $ ps -f
       UID   PID  PPID  C    STIME TTY       TIME COMMAND
   ranga    5779  4411  0 13:12:47 pts/0     0:00 ps -f
   ranga    4411  4403  0 12:45:42 pts/0     0:00 -bash
  [ hp-ux-ia64 ~ ] $ pldd 4411
  4411:   /usr/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/bash
  /usr/lib/hpux32/dld.so
  /usr/local/lib/hpux32/libtermcap.so
  /usr/local/lib/hpux32/libintl.so
  /usr/local/lib/hpux32/libiconv.so
  /usr/lib/hpux32/libdl.so.1
  /usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1
  [ hp-ux-ia64 ~ ] $ gcore 4411
  [ hp-ux-ia64 ~ ] $ gdb -q /usr/bin/bash core.4411

  warning: Load module /usr/bin/bash has been stripped.
  Debugging information is not available.

  (no debugging symbols found)...Core was generated by `bash'.

  (no debugging symbols found)...
  warning: Load module /usr/local/lib/hpux32/libtermcap.so has been stripped.
  Debugging information is not available.

  (no debugging symbols found)...
  #0  0x60000000c05660f0:0 in _waitpid_sys+0x30 () from /usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1
  (gdb) x/s *(char**)__envp
  0x200000007ffffeae:      "USER=ranga"
  (gdb)                           
  :                             
  0x200000007fffff45:      "SSH_CLIENT=3.3.3.3 50072 22"
  :
  0x200000007fffffe4:      "SFTP_PERMIT_CHOWN=1"
  (gdb)
  0x200000007ffffff8:      ""
  ```

Comment: I eager to find out way  without gcore and gdb